# Are import statements preventing my python program from running on a different Windows 10 computer?

Tags: python, import, python-import

So, I've made a keylogger program on python for education purposes.
During the making of this keylogger I've had to install pip and keyboard import zip files and all sorts of stuff on my computer (Windows 10 operating system). As you can see, the program imports keyboard module. And I'm worried that if I were to run the program on a different Windows 10 environment then the program wouldn't run, because keyboard module is not installed. How would I get around this issue? Would I have to use a compiler or something? Can someone please explain this to me? A snippet of my code is below.

```
import keyboard
import os
import os.path
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import time
import smtplib



# keystroke array
stroke_log = []
```

Comment: All third-party modules, external files and resources and the Python interpreter would need to be present on the other machine in order for the script for work as intended. You can bundle these dependencies along with your script, by "freezing" them as a standalone executable. Look into PyInstaller.

Comment: Look into "virtual environments" and creating a "requirements.txt" using `pip freeze`